# Slow Datagrid in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

i have a very slow ItemsControl with up to 5 DataGrids in it. (displays next to each other) Everytime when i update this Control my whole UI lags extremly (~10sec). Each Datagrid has ~50-100 items with 4 predifined columns (not autogenerated). The itemsources of the grids get update at the same time.

Here is my XAML:

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="icjudges"  ItemsSource="{Binding Judges}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname}" Margin="4" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGrid.DataContext>
                                <CollectionViewSource>
                                    <CollectionViewSource.Source>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource selectedtrickrankingconv}">
                                            <Binding Path="TrickRankings" />
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentRunEntry.SelectedTrick" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </CollectionViewSource.Source>
                                </CollectionViewSource>
                            </DataGrid.DataContext>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank" Binding="{Binding Rank}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource centerheaderstyle}" MinWidth="20" CellStyle="{StaticResource centercellstyle}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Trick.Entry.Athlete.NameShort}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource leftheaderstyle}"   MinWidth="100" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Run" Binding="{Binding Trick.Entry.Run.Number}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource centerheaderstyle}"  MinWidth="20" CellStyle="{StaticResource centercellstyle}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding ValueFormatted}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource rightheaderstyle}"   MinWidth="30" CellStyle="{StaticResource rightcellstyle}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any Ideas how i can speed up that rendering process? It's really important for me that my UI stays responsive when I update the datagrids.
I have also tried to replace the Datagrids with ListViews but it's almost as slow as before.

I think i found the issue, here is the converter that provides the data:

```
    public class SelectedTrickJudgeScoreRankingsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Count() != 2)
            return null;
        if (values.Any(x => x == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || x == null))
            return null;

        IEnumerable<JudgeRanking> Rankings = (IEnumerable<JudgeRanking>) values[0];
        Trick CurrentTrick = (Trick)values[1];

        return Rankings.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Trick.Number == CurrentTrick.Number).ScoresSorted;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

    public IEnumerable<Score> ScoresSorted
    {
        get { return Scores.Where(s => s.IsValid).OrderBy(s => s.Rank); }
    }

public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (Value == null)
                return false;
            if (Value.Value >= (decimal)Trick.Entry.ContestPart.MinScore && Value.Value <= (decimal)Trick.Entry.ContestPart.MaxScore)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

if i return ScoresSorted it's very slow, if i only return Scores (unsorted) it's way faster, but i have no idea what to change because i need it sorted

I have programmed a small test application that demonstates the lag of the UI,
you can download it here. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AreXFr2kgVXYjacFH0-MZsnOARPLEA

KR Manu

Comment: xaml markup is only half of wpf program. where is data? markup without  data isn't a [mcve]

Comment: Somethings to start investigating(do it one by one to find out the culprit): disable virtualization where it is activated (again, one by one), use fixed sizes on your WPF Grid inside the DataTemplate, use fixed sizes for the DataGridTextColumn. Looks like an auto sizing issue to me.

Comment: You may want to rethink how you are setting up your data source. The converter is recreating the data source everytime it is called, which is very slow.  Take a look at this post, http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/, and see if you can get rid of the converter.  Initial load time may not be great but after that you should see a huge performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this behavior too. But i found a work around by replacing those `DataGrids` with `ListBox` and have their `ItemsPanel` redefined as so:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

and before it, just create a grid with the amount of columns you need (in order to simulate headers).

It works just fine for me.

Comment: well, it makes things a little bit better i guess but the UI is still lagging to much. I have also tried replacing the datagrid with a listbox or gridview but nothing worked so far

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth ListBox with UniformGrid as ItemsPanel?

Comment: yes, i replaced the whole datagrid but it's still lagging, it must have something to do with the sorted IEnumarable, if i bind directy to an observablecollection which is unsorted it's blazing fast

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth I admit i only used Observable collections.. was it fast with DataGrids or ListBoxes with uniform grids as panels?